# List PSSnapins that could be installed

Tags: powershell

I want to display a list of PSSnapins that I can pick and install, I don't need the default one and I don't want to search the internet for specific snapin, is there a way to list all that are generally available in an official repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/) is the 'official' repository of PowerShell modules.  You can use the `Find-Package` cmdlet to list the available ones - running it just now shows there are over 3500 packages available.

More information: [PackageManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/packagemanagement/?view=powershell-6)

Comment: Hi @boxdog, I know about Find-Package, but I can't understand if there is a way to only display snapins without displaying modules?

Comment: Not sure why you'd be so interested in snap-ins, given that they are deprecated in favour of modules, but the metadata of each item from the gallery contains an `ItemType` property that might help, though they all appear to be set to 'module'.  Get it like this: `([xml]$package.SwidTagText).SoftwareIdentity.Meta.ItemType`